# App (true) and OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension (false) do not both set use_frameworks

Tags: react-native, react-native-onesignal

I am getting error on running `npx pod-install` after integrating OneSignal into my **React Native** project:

*App (true) and OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension (false) do not both set use_frameworks!.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that your application has **use_frameworks!**, however your *OneSignal* target in **Podfile** doesn't.

You have to implicitly tell OneSignal target to set **use_frameworks!**

1. Open **Podfile**
2. Add **use_frameworks!** inside **OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension** target:

```
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0', '< 4.0'
end
```

3. Run **npx pod-install** again